# Raplace a matched number with it's corresponding line in other file in sed

Tags: regex, bash, dictionary, replace, sed

I have a file with this type of lines:

> |||
>
> I want to go to (6025) from (7219)
>
> I want to go
>
> To (6025)
>
> From (7219)
>
> |||

And other file with one word per line called "dictionary".

The goal is to replace each match ([0-9]+) with it's corresponding line in the dictionary file.

I have though in doing somthing like this:

`sed -n 's/.*\(([0-9]\+)\).*/LINE IN DICTIONARY/p' input`

But I don't know how to concatenate the regex with the file replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU awk:

```
$ cat -n dictionary 
     1  foo
     2  bar
     3  baz
     4  world
$ cat file
I want to go to (1)(2) (4)!
$ gawk '             
    NR==FNR {words[NR]=$0; next} 
    {
        while ( match($0, /(^.*)\(([[:digit:]]+)\)(.*)/, m) ) {
            $0 = m[1] words[m[2]] m[3]
        }
        print
    }
' dictionary myfile
```

```
I want to go to foobar world!
```

or perl

```
perl -MPath::Class -e '
    @words = file("dictionary")->slurp( chomp => 1 );
    ($text = file("myfile")->slurp) =~ s/\((\d+)\)/$words[$1 - 1]/ge;
    print $text;
'
```

Comment: It works! And the reverse process? To transform each word from the inputFile that exists in the dictionary to the corresponding index?

Thanks!